# Where do I store keys provided in Paramiko demo_server.py example?

Tags: ssh, paramiko

I am trying to run the Paramiko demo_server.py example found here: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/main/demos/demo_server.py. I want to ssh into the server using the Windows command prompt and OpenSSH.

Where am I supposed to put the demo keys so that I am able to log into the server I am running?

When looking up setting up a SSH connection I am seeing plenty of things about generating a key. I am unsure if this demo wants you to generate a new key and then rename it since there aren't instructions.

Comment: What *"demo keys"*? Your question is unclear.  So far it does not look like a programming question either.

Comment: There are ssh keys in the same folder as this example: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/main/demos. This is what I mean by demo keys. You are right in that it may not be a programming question, I wasn't sure where to ask. @MartinPrikryl